# Upgrading the build.gradle of the android app(AIDE)

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, aide-ide

i am using an android app called AIDE to build android apps, how do i get to upgrade its gradle as the current version that I am using is

**Here**
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1+

and I would like to upgrade to the latest version 3.3. Please how do I go about this as it will help to make my work and studies smooth

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try change classpath on build.gradle, then refresh build and run app?
check
~/build .gradle
not
~/app/build.gradle

maybe you need upgrade your AIDE to PRO for save the change

Answer (score 0):

If you have the pro version, try to delete the line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+'
```

if that doesnt't help, copy this line to build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```